# cannot load such file middleman-core - (middleman server)

Tags: ruby, server, middleman

I've installed all prerequisites for middleman project to proceed further 
 but at `middleman server` causing an issue
what actually it is said to me

> PS C:\First_MP> middleman server
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.1.7/bin/middleman:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- middleman-core (LoadError)
>   from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.1.7/bin/middleman:12:in`
>           `from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/middleman:23:in`load'
>           from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/middleman:23:in `'

I need to know what I'm missing or need to change that my project will run

Directories in my PC.
Ruby:

```
C:\Ruby22-x64
```

and 
DevKit:

```
C:\Ruby22-x64\RubDevKit
```

creating Project

```
C:\ middleman init First_MP
```

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]
```

and Dev kit

```
DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're in the right directory?

Comment: yes i'm at my Project directory that i was created in C:

Comment: If `middleman init` can find the right files, then `middleman server` should find them too. Try `middleman init` a second project, in a different directory, to see if it's truly a problem with `server` or just Ruby can't find the libraries at all. `bundle exec middleman server` might help find the libraries.

Comment: **RESOLVED** i just add these two lines in Gemfile gem "middleman-cli"

gem "middleman-core"

Comment: and hit with this line "bundle exec middleman server"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if this problem is resolved, I think posting an answer will help anyone having this problem in future.

The error log provides enough information to go about tackling this problem.

> require': cannot load such file -- middleman-core (LoadError)

`middleman-core` gem is a dependency of `middleman` gem. In my `Gemfile.lock`,

```
middleman (4.1.6)
  coffee-script (~> 2.2)
  compass-import-once (= 1.0.5)
  haml (>= 4.0.5) 
  kramdown (~> 1.2)
  middleman-cli (= 4.1.6)
  middleman-core (= 4.1.6)
  sass (>= 3.4.0, < 4.0)
```

If your `Gemfile.lock` doesn't have this, put the gems yourself. In this case, add these to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'middleman-cli'
gem 'middleman-core'
```